# orderless doesn't handle spaces when searching for completions

Tags: completion, minibuffer, completion-styles

I'm trying [orderless](https://github.com/oantolin/orderless) and using the basic configuration from the github page, I'm not seeing the expected behavior when using spaces: the github page suggests that, with the suggested basic configuration, using `describe-function` with the input "`eis ff`" would show many results, including `ediff-merge-region-is-non-clash-to-skip`.

But when I try that, I get no matches.

Similarly, I was expecting that, say `M-x pack list` would show `list-packages`, but it shows nothing.

Overall using spaces in my minibuffer prompt always yields no results.

I'm using vertico and marginalia, and don't seem to otherwise have any fancy completion configuration.

How do I get the basic, well, orderless behavior with multiple space-separated words?

Comment: Can you add the actual configuration you're using? Not only will this help your question stand the test of time (seeing as the github page can/will change), but will also confirm that your config was copied unchanged.

Comment: I'm using the exact thing suggested on the github page: I have `(completion-styles '(orderless basic))` and `(completion-category-overrides '((file (styles basic partial-completion)))`. I've tried this even with `emacs -q` and it just doesn't ever seem to do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `fido-mode` is messing this up. When I have `fido-mode` enabled, it doesn't work; when I turn that off, something like

```
M-x find dir na
```

does indeed do an order-less search: it finds `find-name-dired` and `dired-find-alternate-file`.

Another dumb thing is that the example I kept using from the orderless github page -- `C-h f eis ff` -- doesn't work because for some reason none of those ediff functions exist for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add orderless to `completion-styles`:

`(setq completion-styles '(substring orderless basic))`.

If you have that, it should work with spaces (I use vertico + orderless regularly in a minimal emacs environment and that's my only config for it.)

If it's not working with that variable set, perhaps to get it it working first in a minimal emacs environment.